# Multiple attempts to find the best icon

Tags: ruby

I have a series if statements where I am trying to find the highest resolution file in an set of files. Is there a way that I can refactor this code to be shorter and or cleaner?

```
begin
  icon = icons.find { |name, _| name.downcase.include? 'xxxhdpi' }
  if icon.nil?
    icon = icons.find { |name, _| name.downcase.include? 'xxhdpi' }
  end
  if icon.nil?
    icon = icons.find { |name, _| name.downcase.include? 'xhdpi' }
  end
  if icon
    File.open(tmp_icon.path.to_s, 'wb') do |f| 
      icon { |_, data| f.write data }
      s3_icon = bucket.objects[icon_path].write(Pathname.new(tmp_icon.path),
                                              content_type: 'image/png')
      icon_url = s3_icon.public_url(secure: true)
    end
  end
ensure
  tmp_icon.close
  tmp_icon.unlink
end
```

Comment: Re your last comment (I deleted my answer), you get `nil` because you are comparing resolutions to the entire icon name, and not the resolution part. So you are doing `xxxhdpi == entire_icon_name` which will be `nil`. Come to think of it, my solution would not guarantee the highest res first, so I deleted it for now.

Comment: Please do not update code in question after receiving answers.

Comment: @Jamal I need to update the question do to a fault in my original code. icon has no named attributes

Comment: @AntarrByrd: If they came from answers, then the original code must stay intact.  All answers are supposed to review just that, and it shouldn't morph according to the answers.

Comment: @Jamal the changes I posted last are not from the answers. But one of the answerers has requested that I do post update that are related to the answer, which is what you removed earlier.

Comment: @AntarrByrd: Updates somehow related to answers can still cause confusion for other readers.  If there are multiple issues, they can eventually be addressed in a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A case-insensitive regex match with alternation seems like it fits your use case. Also note the use of a guard clause rather than using an if statement with no else.

```
begin
  icon = icons.find { |entry| entry.name =~ /xxxhdpi|xxhdpi|xhdpi/i }
  return unless icon.defined?
  File.open(tmp_icon.path.to_s, 'wb') { |f| f.write icon[:data] }
  s3_icon = bucket.objects[icon_path].write(Pathname.new(tmp_icon.path),
                                            content_type: 'image/png')
  icon_url = s3_icon.public_url(secure: true)
ensure
  tmp_icon.close
  tmp_icon.unlink
end
```

Comment: The case insensitive regex match will not give precedence to high DPI images like the OP wants. Consider this list: `a_xhdpi, a_xxxhdpi, a_xxhdpi` It will return the `a_xhdpi` image instead of the `a_xxxhdpi` image.

Comment: I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method `icon' for main:Object` with this code. Even with the unless statement

Comment: Sorry, I updated to use `icon.defined?`.

Comment: You have broken the argorithm. It had to iterate all the icons for `xxx` at first, but you'll stop on the first if it's `x`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to properly give precedence to higher DPI images, you need to do three separate finds like your code already does. However, this part can be cleaned up, as well as getting rid of the unnecessary `icon.try do ... end` call.

```
begin
  icon = icons.find { |name, _| name.downcase.include? 'xxxhdpi' }
      || icons.find { |name, _| name.downcase.include? 'xxhdpi' }
      || icons.find { |name, _| name.downcase.include? 'xhdpi' }

  return unless icon.defined?

  File.open(tmp_icon.path.to_s, 'wb') { |f| f.write icon[:data] }
  s3_icon = bucket.objects[icon_path].write(Pathname.new(tmp_icon.path),
                                            content_type: 'image/png')
  icon_url = s3_icon.public_url(secure: true)
ensure
  tmp_icon.close
  tmp_icon.unlink
end
```

Comment: Please look at the update above. I icon still is nil in your code.

Comment: Then it didn't find a suitable match.

Comment: I see the edits you made to your post. I updated my answer.

Comment: When I do `icons.each { |n, _| puts "icon -> #{n}"}
# finds 4 files
# icon -> res/drawable-ldpi-v4/launcher.png
# icon -> res/drawable-mdpi-v4/launcher.png
# icon -> res/drawable-hdpi-v4/launcher.png
# icon -> res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/launcher.png` it finds 4

Comment: @AntarrByrd: Can you please update your post with this information? It seems pretty critical.

Comment: Last time I did Jamal removed it. I will try again.

Comment: For increased generality, consider writing the first part: `arr = ['xxxhdpi', 'xxhdpi', 'xhdpi']; icon = arr.reduce(nil) { |icon, res| icon || icons.find { |name, _| name.downcase.include?(res) } }`.